# Character Movement: How to pause character when not moving. XNA

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to stop my character from doing its animation when there is no movement or action keys pressed.
I have a function that pauses the animation but I'm not sure how to implement it without stopping the characters movement completely.

Here's what I'm doing in my `PlayerSprite` update:

```cs
 this.move = (int)(GameData.PLAYER_MOVE_INCREMENT * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds);
 if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(leftKey))
 {
     MoveBy(-move, 0);
     this.PRESENTATIONINFO.SPRITEEFFECTS = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
 }
 if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(rightKey))
 {
     MoveBy(move, 0);
     this.PRESENTATIONINFO.SPRITEEFFECTS = SpriteEffects.None;
 }
 if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isFirstKeyPress(Keys.Space))
 {
     bPause = !bPause;
 }
```

The animation will pause when i press space bar but i want it to pause when there are no keys pressed to give the effect of the character standing still.

Thanks in advance.

I fixed it by doing this:

```cs
bPause = true;
this.move = (int)(GameData.PLAYER_MOVE_INCREMENT * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds);
if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(leftKey))
{
    bPause = false;
    MoveBy(-move, 0);
    this.PRESENTATIONINFO.SPRITEEFFECTS = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
}
if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(rightKey))
{
    bPause = false;
    MoveBy(move, 0);
    this.PRESENTATIONINFO.SPRITEEFFECTS = SpriteEffects.None;
}
if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isFirstKeyPress(Keys.Space))
{
    bPause = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(leftKey))
{
   bPause = false;
   MoveBy(-move, 0);
   this.PRESENTATIONINFO.SPRITEEFFECTS = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
}
else if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(rightKey))
{
   bPause = false;
   MoveBy(move, 0);
   this.PRESENTATIONINFO.SPRITEEFFECTS = SpriteEffects.None;
}
else
{
   bPause = true;
}
```